# Retrieve SlideSize from a SlidePart in OpenXML

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I created a little program that generates a pptx file using a template pptx and various images. I want to adjust the size of the images depending on the image size and the size of the current slide.
I found a code snippet that retrieves the `SlideSize` from a `PresentationPart`. In my method scope I only have a `SlidePart` though. 
**Can I access the `SlideSize` from there? Or do I have to pass the `PresentationPart` as a parameter?**
 Here is the snippet:

```
SlideSize slideSize = parentPresPart.Presentation.Descendants<SlideSize>().First();
```

Sorry for this very specific question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this using the following code. Not sure if there is a more proper way of doing this.

```
PresentationPart presPart = slidePart.GetParentParts().FirstOrDefault(z => z is PresentationPart) as PresentationPart;
SlideSize slideSize = null;
if (presPart != null)
{
    slideSize = presPart.Presentation.GetFirstChild<SlideSize>();
}
```